# build target dependency in Xcode with preprocessor options

Tags: xcode, dependencies, preprocessor

I have an app target in Xcode (test target) and a library target in my project. The app target is supposed to test library target. The test app target has the library target as a dependency but for testing purposes I need to build library with some specific preprocessor definition (e.g `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="TEST_MODE"`). I haven't managed to find a way to achieve it in Xcode so I'm wondering if it's possible.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the way ?